# Cannot find status check in github > repository > settings > branches

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm following the documentation but I don't see my check available in the search bar.

The documentation seems to think that the check will show up automatically but its not happening for me. It is a private repository but I also have Pro.

Do I need to have anything special in my yaml file? Or am I doing something else wrong? Do I just need to wait?

[image]

**test.yml**

```
name: Foo

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    timeout-minutes: 2
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'yarn'
    - run: yarn install --immutable
    - run: yarn lint
    - run: yarn types
```

[image]

Comment: That field is autocomplete -- have you tried and searched by name?

Comment: @rethab I have but I’ll check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching on "build" worked.

I had only searched by "Foo" and "test". smh.

Thank you @rethab